Can't create transaction manager in unit tests after migrating from Spring 5 to 6 and Hibernate 5 to 6
I am tasked with migrating our web application which runs in Tomcat 9.5 to run under Tomcat 10.  This involves migrating from javax.* to jakarta.* so I used the migrator tool to do the rudimentary work of renaming packages.  I am compiling and running under Java 17.  However, I am stuck on getting the persistence unit tests work under Spring 6.0.22 and Hibernate core 6.3.5.Final.  I followed examples of how to setup the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and my spring context file setting this up looks like this.
<beans>    
<bean id="persistenceDataSource" class="com.infogix.component.kernel.export.db.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${db.driver}" p:url="${db.url}"
          p:username="${db.user}" p:password="${db.password}"/>

    <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer">allow</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred">org.hibernate.id.enhanced.PooledLoOptimizer</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.generator.stored_last_used">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="persistenceDataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.infogix.component.**.export.fdt.**</value>
                <value>com.infogix.component.**.rsc.impl.**</value>
                <value>com.infogix.component.datastore.ent.impl.**</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class=
            "org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
</beans>

When I run unit tests they are not running in the Tomcat or any container so I guess this is more like a standalone app.  We are not using JTA to manage transactions across multiple databases.  We have a single database (Postgres 10).  As mentioned above we used Hibernate 5 with Spring 5 and so we were injecting sessionFactory everywhere where we needed to interact with the database.
 
All our unit tests are configured with these types of annotations.
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/persistence-test-context.xml"})
With the above xml configuration I see that NoJtaPlatform is selected as JTA provider which returns null TransactionManager.  Since we don't use JTA I don't know how I can force it to do the right thing i.e. create transaction manager.  We are specifying JpaTransactionManager so I assumed it would work.
The error I am getting when running unit tests is:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified
Should we be using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean during unit testing since we are not running inside a container?  BTW, by 'Container' do they mean full Jakarta EE container or just a servlet container like Tomcat?
If yes what how should it be configured to properly create a transaction manager.
Should we be injecting SessionFactory or EntityManager?
I tried using these JTA platform driver so transaction manager could be created but I still couldn't get unit tests to work.
naryana-jta = { module = "org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta", version = "6.0.3.Final" }
wildfly-transaction-client = { module = "org.wildfly.transaction:wildfly-transaction-client", version = "3.0.5.Final"}
I am not sure if this is even the right way since we are not using JTA.
I also tried using LocalEntityFactoryBean but it won't let me configure datasource and packagesToScan so I don't know if it will work since we are using package scanning these 2 annotations.
@Entity
@Table(name="CAF_DEVENV")
We are also using spring @Transactional annotation a lot.
Any help will be appreciated.

Remove the hibernate.current_session_context_class property from the configuration.

When I do this, Hibernate creates NoJTAPlatform.  NoJTAPlatform returns null transaction manager and when it does that currentSessionContext is null and session can't be open and I get HibernateException 'No CurrentSessionContext configured'.  This is why I was wondering if I should switch to using LocalEntityFactoryBean instead of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.

You aren't using JTA so yuou need to remove it. Spring will set its own current_session_context_class for integration. Which makes me wonder you have the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  but are using the SessionFactoryz internally?

Thank you for confirming that LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is correct. Finally I found the problem.  I was injecting EntityManagerFactory into my services and then using unwrap method to get Hibernate Session.  Many examples on Baeldung showed using EntityManager not EntityManagerFactory.  So I added EntityManager with annotation @PersistenceContext into my service.  Then I enabled logging for org.hibernate and org.springframework.orm and I saw EntityManager and transactions are created.  Then I realized I had to rework calls where I used Hibernate session to use entityManager.

You can unwrap the EntityManager to a Session if you want.
